# How to make the angularjs json schema form readonly dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, json, forms

I have been using Angularjs json form module https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form. I want to control the readonly property of the entire form using a variable inside my viewcontroller, which means that I also would like to refresh the entire form whenever I changed its readonly property. I have been experimenting the {formDefaults: {readonly: true}}. But it seems that it doesn't response well to the change of the variable. And setting the global schema's property readonly also doesn't response to the change. What is the solution to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions are outlined [here](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/issues/225#issuecomment-70834629), though I'm not too happy about either. There were [suggestions](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/issues/597) to allow passing a function to the `readonly` property like with `condition` which would've been a nicer solution, but it seems they were abandoned.

I grudgingly solved this using jQuery while we find a way to remove SchemaForm in our project (since it doesn't seem to be maintained any more).

```
$('input#my_field_id').prop('disabled', true);
```